# Add StackPanel and more than one TextBlock inside Button

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I want to add a number of `TextBlock`s inside a `Button`. How can I add a number of them, along with `StackPanel`s or `Canvas`es, in C#, as shown below in XAMAL

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
         <TextBlock Text="DEF"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: try adding a list with multiple items as textbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tb1 = new TextBlock() { Text = "TextBlock 1" };
        var tb2 = new TextBlock() { Text = "TextBlock 2" };

        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(tb1);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(tb2);

        var button = new Button() { Content = stackPanel };

        this.Content = button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about an enclosing control of csharpfolk's answer. This would help to get a reuseable control.

The text strings are good to use as a dependency property. :)

Regards,
- Tobbo